# Moving functions from a base WebApi controller into a testable service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have inherited a WebApi2 application that has a very heavy `BaseController` without the use of DI and doesn't have any tests.

I am trying to create a service and move some of the logic from the base controller out as I believe this will make my life easier to test the application and maintain it moving forward.

A couple of examples of methods in the base

```
public virtual string GetControllerName()
{
    return this.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType.Name;
}

public virtual string GetActionName()
{
    return this.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
}
```

I have 2 dependence on `ControllerContext` & `ActionContext` if I can abstract these out into a service I can moq the results so my tests wont have a dependency on `this.Request`

Does anyone have any pointers on how I can get my service to work. I have this so far

```
public ApplicationService(ILog log, 
                          HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage)
{
    _log = log;
    _httpRequestMessage = httpRequestMessage;
}

public virtual string GetControllerName()
{
    // return this.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType.Name;
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public virtual string GetActionName()
{
    return _httpRequestMessage.GetActionDescriptor().ActionName;
}
```

Passing `httpRequestMessage` feels a little wrong...maybe this is ok....to access `ControllerContext` I would need to pass `HttpControllerContext` which again feels wrong.

Does anyone have any suggestions on a clean approach I can use for my service which will allow me to be able to test without to much of a headache?

Comment: Just a hunch, but when I see methods in a base class like GetControllerName or WhatClassIsBeingUsed etc... it's usually a good indication that it wasn't designed correctly in the first place. If a base class needs to know what child class is being used, it's not good design. Since I have no idea what those methods you mentioned are being used for, this is just a guess based on past experience. YMMV

Comment: I agree, they are used for logging. There is another couple of logging methods that call those functions so the logs contain details of the action and controller. There are few others that use HttpRquestMessage to get details from the header of the request, I just didnt want to put too much into my original question

Comment: All that header reading and parsing might work well with an ActionFilter.  Your service really shouldn't know anything about the calling semantics of the controller.  it should only get passed what it needs to do it's job.  You probably want logging at both the controller level and the service level so that you aren't passing the entire HttpRequestMessage